# PHP form sending html email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

Hi there i'm relatively new to php. 
I've tried to build a contact form that generates a nice html email. So far i've succeeded in redirecting to my "thank you_page" if the form is send. I've even succeeded in the html setup. The only thing I can't get to work are de form variables.

I just can't get them to show in the html email that's been send out.

Can someone please tell what I've got to do, to solve this problem.

My php code looks like this:

http://www.wvansonsbeek.nl/contact_process.html (I know the extentions must be renamed to .php in order for the script to work properly, I've just gave it an html extention for you to examine my source code)

Many thanks in advance!!

Ralph

Comment: please read more about [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), PHP variables inside single quota are just considered as string not variable for example: `echo '$var';` while you can use double quota for printing it `echo "$var";`

Comment: please post code here, not link to it

Comment: remove `header ('location: contact_bedankt.html');` line to see what error you are getting. Then post the error.

Comment: @ Dagon: I sadly can't post my code here because it's to long

Comment: @ Prashant Baid: When removing the header ('location: contact_bedankt.html'); line I'm getting a blank page as a result.

Comment: @ AKAM: Thanks for tip! I've read some info about PHP strings. Changing some double quota's my de code made it possible display the variables html email. =))